# Running my world generation code ends up in 2 or more ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions

Tags: java

So I'm coding my text-based game with world generation and my friend coded the world generation. He's away right now so I have to ask this.
The code should generate an array with the X and Y positions of chests that spawn in random positions. The packages used are: java.util.Scanner,
java.util.Arrays,
java.util.Random,
Class is declared but I'm not including it in this snippet.
The Code for the method *worldgen()*:

```
static double[] worldgen() {
    //coded by *my friend, name censored*
    int random_int_1 = 0;
    int random_int_2 = 0;
    int x;
    int y;
    int chest_x;
    int chest_y;
    double[] chest_x_values;
    double[] chest_y_values;
    int mineral_x;
    int mineral_y;
    // chest_x_and_y_values[something (or else)] = chest_x_values[something];
    // chest_x_and_y_values[something else] = chest_y_values[something];
    Random rand1 = new Random();
    int num_of_chests = rand1.nextInt(100);
    chest_x_values = new double[num_of_chests];
    chest_y_values = new double[num_of_chests];


    while (random_int_1 <= num_of_chests)
    {
        Random rand2 = new Random();
        chest_x = rand2.nextInt(301);
        System.out.println(chest_x);
        chest_x_values[random_int_1] = chest_x;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chest_x_values));
        if(random_int_1 <= num_of_chests) {
            random_int_1++;
            System.out.println(random_int_1);
        }
    }

    while (random_int_2 <= num_of_chests)
    {
        Random rand3 = new Random();
        chest_y = rand3.nextInt(301);
        chest_y_values[random_int_2] = chest_y;
        random_int_2 = random_int_2 + 1;
    }
    int random_int_3 = num_of_chests;
    random_int_1 = 0;
    random_int_2 = 0;

    double[] chest_x_and_y_values = new double[random_int_3 = random_int_3*2+1];
    
    while (random_int_1 <= random_int_3) {
        chest_x_and_y_values[random_int_1] = chest_x_values[random_int_1];
        random_int_1 = random_int_1 + 1;
    }
    
    chest_x_and_y_values[random_int_1+1] = -1;

    while (random_int_2 <= random_int_3) {
        chest_x_and_y_values[random_int_1 + 1 + random_int_2] = chest_y_values[random_int_2];
        random_int_2 = random_int_2 + 1;
    }
    
    return chest_x_and_y_values;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //coded by EnZon3
    Scanner uIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");
    System.out.println("     *game name censored*      ");
    System.out.println("    1: Generate new world..    ");
    System.out.println("  2: Generate w/ custom seed.. ");
    System.out.println("      3: See world data        ");
    System.out.println("           4: Exit             ");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");
    int option = uIn.nextInt();
    if (option > 4) {
        System.err.println("Error 0x1: Not an option");
    }
    while (option != 4) {
        if (option == 1) {
            double[] world = worldgen();
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(world));

        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
Index 77 out of bounds for length 77 at
******.worldgen(******.java:35) at ******.main(******.java:86)

I've tried tweaking the values but that didn't work

Comment: Hi @EnZon3, welcome to StackOverflow. If you have specific questions about common (or less common) programming issues, go for it, ask your question. Though questions should be based on your own researches. StackOverflow should not be used for fixing your code and not at all for fixing your homework or things like this. Please focus your question and first try to understand your own code.

Comment: Anyway, there is a lot of things to fix here. You may want to visualize the arrays and their sizes for yourself to know what you want. I mostly draw myself those input and output states on paper and try to find out the way without a computer. You'll get a much better code doing so. Also think about the fact, that random numbers go from ZERO to a specified maximum. And if num_of_chests would be ZERO, the arrays would get zero sized. Try to choose a different range for those kinds of variables. I also think you want to fix the size of chest_x_and_y_values. random_int_3 = random_int_3*2+1 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
while (random_int_1 <= num_of_chests)
```

This should be < (strictly less than), remember arrays are 0 indexed.

```
while (random_int_2 <= num_of_chests)
```

Same thing here

```
    while (random_int_1 <= random_int_3) {
    chest_x_and_y_values[random_int_1] = chest_x_values[random_int_1];
    random_int_1 = random_int_1 + 1;
}
```

`random_int_3` is `2 * num_of_chests +1`, and `chest_x_values` is a list of length `num_of_chests`. In this part, `random_int_1` can go all the way up to `2 * num_of_chests +1` which is higher than `chest_x_values`.

Comment: Didn't work. Still get the same error.
Try actually compiling and running it

Comment: I changed the conditions in the last two while loops to `random_int_1 < num_of_chests` and `random_int_2 < num_of_chests`. I also added the line `option = uIn.nextInt();` in the very last while loop (the one that handles input) , so it doesn't go into an infinite loop. I compiled it and ran it, it works.